# PHP Redirect in a loop

Tags: php

I am checking a column within a database, dependant on what is in the column
I want to redirect to a specific page.

This is what I currently have:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE email = '" . $_SESSION['user'] . "'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

        if($result->num_rows > 0)
        {

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $lastleftCheck = $row['lastLeft'];
            }

        }

        if ($lastleftCheck == "0") {
             header('Location: members.php');
        }
        if ($lastleftCheck == "1") {
             header('Location: members_step2.php');
        }
        if ($lastleftCheck == "2") {
             header('Location: members_step3.php');
        }
```

But it keeps going in a loop, what am I doing wrong can someone please help.

Comment: `string[] filelines = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(130).ToArray();` ?

Comment: Add some example data ... you give us a hard time figuring out a solution.

Comment: the string I declare at first I would like to keep as ReadAllLines, how can I read the file later in my application for example from line 130 to the end? @SriramSakthivel by not altering the initial ReallAllLine

Comment: Why you don't want to alter `ReadAllLines`? with `ReadAllLines` to take lines from 130, you'll be creating two arrays, with my solution you'll create only one. If you don't want your code to be efficient, use `ReadAllLines`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

```
var length = filelines.Length;
var columnPosition = 0;

for (int i = 130; i < length; i++)
{
    var index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

    dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[columnPosition].Value = filelines[i];

    //If the column is 3 set the column position to start value, else increment column position by one
    columnPosition = columnPosition == 3 ? 0 : columnPosition + 1;
}
```

Comment: Excatly what I was looking for Richard! Thank you :) ... although this works everything is displayed in one column, how can I get this to seperate, sorry I'm a noob

Comment: This snippet of code will add 'X' lines and put the line text in column with index 0. But you can change de index of column to add in another position. If you want to add the line values at the same row but only add a column it will be a little bit more complicated.

Comment: for example my data I read in is 344 555 666 777 888 and next line reads 555 666 777 888 999 I have columns called maxHR MinHR restHR aveHR, currently  everything displays in maxHR (column with index 0) how can I get it to go to the next column etc etc.

Comment: hi Richard, thanks for the updated answer, but this is not working, what happens is the data is displayed in a column, then a line break and the same data is repeatedly displayed in another column below the first row of the first column, if that makes sense?

Comment: you have checked the file to see if  all lines are equals?

Answer (score 0):

See this code and I hope it will be useful:

```
                    static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    long lineNum = 129;
                    //Load our text file
                    string myFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\test.txt";
                    bool b = System.IO.File.Exists(myFile);
                    if (b == true)
                    {
                        var fA = File.ReadAllLines(myFile);
                        string[] Lines = fA;
                        for (long i=lineNum ;i<fA.Length;i++)
                        {
                            //Do what you want with the lines text from 130 to the end
                            Console.WriteLine(Lines[i].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    long lineCount = File.ReadLines(myFile).Count();
                    Console.WriteLine("These lines read from Line number: 130 " + " to " + lineCount.ToString());
                }
```